# vcgencmd measure_temp doesn't always work

Tags: raspbian-jessie, temperature, cpu

I'm trying to measure my Raspberry Pi's temperature using `vcgencmd measure_temp` but it only works whenever it feels like it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
vc_gencmd_send returned -1
vchi_msg_dequeue -> -1(22)
```

Any idea what might be going on? It just hangs there, I need to use Ctrl+C to get out of there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to do the trick:

```
pi@raspberrypi  $ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
57838
```

Comment: I guess that's why `hwmon` isn't in the stock kernel.  This one is from the ACPI interface, which is probably newer but seems a little strange since the pi doesn't have any power management features; presumably it's used because it standardizes `/sys` better. So I might have been hasty in calling it "daft" ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what might be going on?

No, but the information is available from the kernel via `/sys`.

```
> cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
52996
```

That's thousandths of a degree Celcius (i.e., 52.996 °C).

If your kernel has the hardware monitoring module available (try `sudo modprobe -v hwmon`; if it says `insmod` and a path, you do), and you want something more formal, install `apt-get lm-sensors` and try:

```
> sensors
bcm2835_hwmon-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:        +53.0°C  (high = +85.0°C)
```

Unfortunately this only seems to work on the single core models.

Comment: Hmmm temp1_input does not exist. The "bcm2835_hwmon.0" folder has:  modalias   power/     subsystem/ uevent

Comment: lm-sensors can't find any sensors by the way, and sensor-detect returns: "/sys/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/sensors-detect line 3003."

Comment: Huh -- I use a custom kernel, which probably accounts for that.  Raspbian *should* have a `hwmon` or `bcm2835-hwmon` module available, but looking through a copy of a recent image, I don't see it. The max temp is the "high =" number, btw (85.0°C), but the pi does not significantly change temperature even when maxed out (I just did this for 5 min, it got up to 57 °C); I think the only way to truly heat it up is to overclock it...

Comment: Very interesting. I'll ask another question straight away. In any case, I think i've nailed it with: "cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"

Comment: Also, it does not work at all in Stretch.

Comment: @SDsolar It is more likely because of the model as this was written when there were only the single core BCM2835 ones.  The more generic interface is the one from the accepted answer (`/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`).  That works in Stretch.  The `sensors` CLI, as mentioned, may require kernel modules that aren't included by default in the Pi kernel.

Comment: Understood.    However, the Python alternative is ridiculously simple:  First, `pip install setuptools` then `sudo pip install git+https://github.com/nicmd/vcgencmd.git` then you can use `import vcgencmd` then `CPUc=vcgencmd.temp()` then convert to F with `CPUf=CPUc*1.8+32`  --  works for me.  --- FYI, if Python3, then you would use `pip3`  --  Works for Raspbian Stretch (and Jessie and Wheezy).

Comment: That presumes the python vcgencmd lib isn't going to fall prey to the problem in the original question, whereas the kernel interface is distinct from that.  Anyway, this one is a bit like that Paul Simon song about leaving your lover: `echo "scale=1; $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) / 1000" | bc -l` (I'm a Canuck so Celsius is fine by me.)