# Measuring CPU temperature gives error

Tags: raspbian-buster, temperature

When I run the command `vcgencmd measure_temp` to measure the tempearture of my Raspberry Pi, instead of expected output (e.g. `temp=50.1'C`) it sometimes throws an error as follows:

```
vc_gencmd_send returned -1
vchi_msg_dequeue -> -1(22)
```

It is impossible to even google this to find out more. Can you please advise why this happens and how to prevent it? I have Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vcgencmd measure\_temp doesn't always work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/vcgencmd-measure-temp-doesnt-always-work)

Comment: Only partially, since it looks like and error and the suggested answer provides only a workaround. I would like to understand why this problem occurs at all, what triggers it. More importantly, it seems to me that this `vcgencmd` behaviour is accompanied by other problems (such as disfunctional recording via CSI camera) and can only be solved by reboot.